# Selenium Grid + Jenkins Infrastructure execution

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid

Pardon me for the lengthy description:

I have the following infrastructure where I am attempting to deploy the Selenium grid via Jenkins. For the sake of simplicity, I am using simplified IP addresses.

Machine 1 (Jenkins): 
**IP: 1.1.1.1**

Machine 2 (The Test Script + The Firefox RC instance resides on this)
**IP: 2.2.2.2**

Machine 3 (The IE RC instance resides on this)
**IP: 3.3.3.3**

Now, I am starting instances of RC as follows:
Machine 2:
RC 1: `ant -Dport=5555 -Denvironment=*firefox -Dhost=2.2.2.2 -DhubURL=http://1.1.1.1:4444 launch-remote-control`

Machine 3:
RC 2: `ant -Dport=5556 -Denvironment=*iexplore -Dhost=3.3.3.3 -DhubURL=http://1.1.1.1:4444 launch-remote-control`

After doing this, I am able to establish connection on the Jenkins Selenium console for both Machine 2 and Machine 3.

As far as my test script (residing solely on Machine 2) is concerned - 
For firefox,

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("1.1.1.1",4444,"*firefox","http://mytestURL.com")
```

For IE,

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("1.1.1.1",4444,"*iexplore","http://mytestURL.com")
```

The problem is that I unable to get the test script to execute on **Machine 3**, where the IE instance resides.

What settings do I have to make in the `DefaultSelenium` object to get the test script residing on Machine 2 to execute on Machine 3, via the Jenkins grid?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the host's IP address on Machine 3. This works as expected.